# Make inline table spacing proportionate to page

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

Is there a way to have *multiple tables* line up in a way that is equally spaced on the page?

Here is what I WANT my page to look like:

```
<table class="auto-style4" border="0"  cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:7%" align="right">table 1, cell 1</td>     
        <td style="width:7%" >table 1, cell 2</td>
        <td style="width:7%" align="right">TABLE 2, CELL 1</td>     
        <td style="width:7%" >TABLE 2, CELL 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLDD6QZ6DCV0

BUT my issue is that I need them to be separate tables, because of how the page interacts with other parts of a website.

This is the closest I've been able to get to replicating it with separate tables: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLDD5NFMYBL7

But the problem is that it centers both columns in the middle of the page, rather than spacing them out evenly on the page as in the first example (which is what I want.)

So, my question: In general, is there any way to make separate inline tables that are evenly spaced across the page, as in the first example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are trying to achieve? If yes then I'll add some explanation.

```css
table{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 1 Item 1</td>
      <td>Table 1 Item 2</td>
      <td>Table 1 Item 3</td>
      <td>Table 1 Item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 2 Item 1</td>
      <td>Table 2 Item 2</td>
      <td>Table 2 Item 3</td>
      <td>Table 2 Item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is super close to what I am trying to do, but there is one difference: In the first example in my question, the columns are spaced with equal distance between each other *and* with the edges of the page.

Whereas in your solution, the columns are spaced apart from each other the way I want, but they are up against the sides of the page, which I don't want. 

Any way to make it behave as described?

And this is this something you are trying to achieve, so any explanation welcome.

Comment: Think I answered my own question: change `justify-content:space-between;` to `justify-content:space-around;`

Comment: Great, I am happy I could help. If you don't mind then select it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Btw, I found this a pretty useful explainer for learning more about using flex: https://webagility.com/posts/fluid-layouts-done-right-with-flexbox